# Load div on collapse in Boostrap when screen width is 991px or less

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am trying to optimize the mobile version of my website in Boostrap. I have a div that takes a lot of space on my page and I would like to be able to hide this div on page load for any screen width of 991px or less. I want to give the option to the user to show the div when clicking on a button. I want this div to appear on page load for screen width greater than 992px.

I would like to know if Boostrap offers a way to do so without the use of additional JavaScript and if so, how to do it. If not, what would be the best way to accomplish what I want.

```
<div class="mydiv">
    I want to be hidden on page load for screen width of 991px or less
</div>
<a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mydiv">Show Div &raquo;</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
//hide for displays below 992px
.mydiv {
   dispaly:none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

//show for displays greater thatn 992px
    .mydiv {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

and you can use the bootstrap toggle to switch it on and Off
if you want to hide the button on displays greater than 992px

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #idforyourbutton {
        display:none;
    }
}
```